# TCP Port is disabled on my dedicated server, how to know why?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

The firewall is off on my windows server 2008 r2, and no hardware firewalls, how to know what is blocking my port?

From the comments:

I am trying to connect to TFS from visual studio 2010, it gives me an error message, I can access to TFS server as a web server (port 80), but can't access the TFS port

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://xxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/tfs.

Team Foundation Server Url: http://xxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/tfs.



Possible reasons for failure include:

- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.

- The Team Foundation Server is offline.

- The password has expired or is incorrect.



Technical information (for administrator):

Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Comment: How do you know your port is being blocked? How does this manifest itself and what error messages do you see ?

Comment: I am trying to connect to TFS from visual studio 2010, it gives me an error message, I can access to TFS server as a web server (port 80), but can't access the TFS port.

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio

TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: http://xxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/tfs.

Team Foundation Server Url: http://xxxxxx.xxx:xxxx/tfs.

  

Possible reasons for failure include:

- The name, port number, or protocol for the Team Foundation Server is incorrect.

- The Team Foundation Server is offline.

- The password has expired or is incorrect.



Technical information (for administrator):

Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: What are ways to block some port on windows server 2008 r2?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do would be to confirm that the process is listening on the port and is bound to the correct IP address and uses the correct protocol

```
netstat -abn | findstr <TFSport>
```

you'll get something like

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:17500    0.0.0.0    LISTENING    [Dropbox.exe] (I don't have TFS)
```

which say that the process is bound to all available IPv4 addresses. It may say

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:17500    0.0.0.0    LISTENING    [Dropbox.exe]
```

Which means it's only listening on the 127.0.0.1 IPv4 address.
If the process is running and attached to the port/IP address as you expect and your inbound firewall has the correct port open then the next thing to check is that your workstation's outbound firewall is allowing connections to the server's IP address/port.

Comment: I am sure that TFS is running and ok, i can access TFS from other machines, but I cant do that from a specific server.+